# Random Sample From Data frame and remains

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

How to select remains of data frame after random selection of data?

This will give 80% data. but I want remaining 20% also.

df.sample(frac=0.8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df_sample = df.sample(frac=0.8)
```

and then:

```
df_remains = df[~df.index.isin(df_sample.index)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you also have `numpy` installed, a Pandas dependency, you can do something like this:

```py
import numpy as np

p = .8
msk = np.random.rand(len(df)) < p
sample = df[msk]
remains = df[~msk]
```